# Xerces C++ DOM parse continuation after SchemaLocation error

Tags: c++, xml, dom, xerces

When parsing XML containing:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1"
```

I correctly get an error:

> schemaLocation does not contain namespace-location pairs

but I want to continue processing rather than throwing an exception, as the error really doesn't matter in the context I have. I cant change the XML as another system is generating it. Is there any way to set an option to continue processing or alternatively to disable the validation?